# R - error factor has new levels but cannot find the new levels

Tags: r

I have a problem similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285335/190791

```
> fit = glm(repeater ~ bool_brand * bool_comp * bool_cat + cust_poor_rich + chain, family=binomial(logit), data=tt)#<-- submission 16
> 
> pred = predict(fit, tcv, type = "response")
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor chain has new levels 525
```

but I cannot find the new levels

```
> id <- which(!(tcv$chain %in% levels(tt$chain)))
> id
integer(0)
```

Here are extracts of the data structure for tt and tcv:

```
> str(tt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  112040 obs. of  36 variables:
 $ offer             : int  1198271 1198274 1208329 1208252 1199258 1199258 1208251 1203052 1203052 1200581 ...
 $ id                : Factor w/ 160057 levels "86246","86252",..: 53788 56484 40810 88265 28129 96116 18831 136327 121084 69563 ...
 $ chain             : Factor w/ 130 levels "2","3","4","6",..: 5 41 15 21 15 37 32 63 17 1 ...
etc

> str(tcv)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  48017 obs. of  36 variables:
 $ offer             : int  1197502 1208251 1199256 1200581 1200988 1208251 1197502 1199258 1197502 1198272 ...
 $ id                : Factor w/ 160057 levels "86246","86252",..: 110756 15729 42581 72532 144743 7733 85601 43639 109772 138467 ...
 $ chain             : Factor w/ 130 levels "2","3","4","6",..: 9 44 15 68 4 50 26 15 68 73 ...
etc
```

Comment: Have you checked `which(!(tcv$chain %in% levels(droplevels(tt$chain))))`?

Comment: @Roland I did now. Your command returns two items. What does that mean?

Comment: You have levels (I assume "525") in `tt$chain` for which there are no values in `tt$chain`, but there are values in `tcv$chain`.