# Dummy variables and in- and out-of-sample prediction?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I am trying to predict sales for a retail store. Here are my variables (you can largely ignore the values of the variables, outside of ZipZone; their values are largely irrelevant for this question):

```
storeId    sales    meanTemperature     meanHumidity    ZipZone
1          1350     56.78               61.12           0
2          1230     59.90               45.67           3
3          8476     63.54               49.87           3
4          4357     62.12               65.09           4
5          2314     69.78               68.99           4
6          7812     74.90               59.78           4
7          1350     56.78               61.12           6
8          1230     59.90               45.67           6
9          8476     63.54               49.87           6
10         4357     62.12               65.09           7
11         2314     69.78               68.99           7
12         7812     74.90               59.78           8
...
```

There are 50 unique `storeId` values (i.e. there are fifty stores). I built a regression model in the form of:

```
model <- lm(sales ~ meanTemperature*meanHumidity + ZipZone)
```

I'm currently testing this model's efficacy in terms of in- and out-of-sample prediction, so I've created `inSample` and `outSample` data frames (the former has 40 stores; the latter has 10). The issue, though, is that I have several stores in just one `ZipZone`. For example, the `inSample` table has store 1 (the only store in `ZipZone` 0), while the `outSample` table has store 12 (the only store in `ZipZone` 8). When I run the following:

```
pred <- predict(model, newdata = outSample)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
```

factor ZIPzone has new levels 8

I assume this is because `inSample` doesn't have a store in `ZipZone` 8, while `outSample` does. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: This answer is probably helpful for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285214/predict-lm-with-an-unknown-factor-level-in-test-data

Comment: I don't usually upvote questions that I also close, but in this case I think the question adds something because it included the error message text, which the earlier question did not. Sometimes it's useful to have the actual error text as a search target.

Comment: It would be very helpful if we knew what data types are your columns. You can use `dput` function to provide us with the sample data; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example